# Can I create a graph from mgconsole?

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

I would like to SSH to remote server that runs Memgraph and generate graph as PNG, PDF, JPG, SVG or some graphical format right from mgconsole. Is there an export option for graphics in Cypher that does that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `memgraph` (via Cypher) nor `mgconsole` don't have a capability like that, but luckily there are alternatives :D

You can try to connect by using [Memgraph Lab](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph-lab/), generate a graph and screenshot it. Maybe there is even an image export feature (but not 100% sure). **NOTE:** If you can't connect directly to the instance, but there is SSH access, you can always create [SSH Tunnel](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/tunneling). Back in the days, I've sketched a simple explanation of [SSH tunneling](http://buda.link/posts/ssh_tunneling/index.html).

If you really want an all-in terminal experience, [graphscii](https://github.com/etano/graphscii) is a lovely project that helps visualize graphs in the terminal :D